# Python CSV writer - ignore quoted commas when writing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a Python3 script to download some data from an API and save as a CSV file, but having trouble figuring out the right way to do this, accounting for commas in quoted text.

```
>>> export = get_lead_export_file('9833672b')
>>> print(type(export))
<class 'bytes'>
>>> print(export)
b'company,billingStreet,website,email\n-"Acme, Inc","123 Main St, Suite 23",acme.com,joe@acme.com\n-"Acme, Inc","123 Main St, Suite 23",acme.com,joe@acme.com\n-
```

My function is as follows:

```
    def store_leads(lead_export_job_id):
        export = get_lead_export_file(lead_export_job_id)
        export_decoded = export.decode()
        row_list = export_decoded.rsplit('\n-')

        with open(lead_export_job_id, 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            for row in row_list:
                items = row.rsplit(',')
                writer.writerows(items)
```

But the data gets corrupted, as commas appear within the quoted text (i.e. "123 Main St, Suite 23")

There must be a better way to write the byte data to the CSV without first decoding? And then also a better way for splitting on unquoted commas?

Comment: Is it possible to download the data into a text file with a | delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `quotechar` parameter inside the `csv.writer` example syntax is given below

```py
csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```